# How to know whether current time in DST or not?

Tags: php

How do I know whether the current time of a particular city of the world is in DST or not? Is there a PHP function?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not a PHP person, but it looks like this is feasible - but awkward.

Given a [DateTimeZone](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php), you can find the current offset *and a set of transitions*. So if you ask for the transitions at "now", you can find out information about the current part of the time zone. A slightly modified example from [the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.gettransitions.php):

```
$theTime = time(); # specific date/time we're checking, in epoch seconds. 

$tz = new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles'); 
$transition = $tz->getTransitions($theTime,$theTime); 

# only one array should be returned into $transition.
$dst = $transition[0]['isdst'];
```

Comment: In C at least, `is_dst` is **wrong**.  It tells you if the timezone has daylight savings at some time, not necessarily now.

Comment: @Mikel: I'm not asking the time zone. I'm asking the *transition* which is currently in effect. (Or rather, the result of the previous transition, so the current state.)

Comment: Actually, it looks like FreeBSD and Linux/glibc say `is_dst` is only 1 if daylight savings is in effect at the specified time, so you might be able to ignore my comment if you're on those.  I just remember it's not portable across all systems.

Comment: Here's one of the odd ones out: Win32.  It assumes US time zone.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf12f0hc(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @Jon Skeet What is the difference?  You're still relying on `isdst` aren't you?  If you're guaranteed to be on Linux, it might work, but otherwise be careful and test several different dates and timezones.

Comment: @Mikel: I'm relying on isdst at the specific point in time, not whether the time zone has DST in general. I would *hope* that the PHP libraries would work around issues in the OS support. We're not asking Win32 for time zone information - we're asking the PHP libraries. PHP can implement those time zones however it wants. Given the docs, it looks like it uses timezonedb.

Comment: @Jon Skeet Yes, you're probably right, but PHP timezone handling has had bugs in the past, so best to double check.

Comment: Minor nit: `$tz-getTransitions` should almost certainly be `$tz->getTransitions`.  The error is in the PHP example you linked to too.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it sounds like `isdst` is supposed to do the right thing, but I've been bitten before, so here's a quick port of my C++ timezone code to PHP:

```
// given a timezone and a timestamp
// return true if timezone has DST at timestamp, false otherwise
// timezone defaults to current timezone
// timestamp defaults to now
function is_dst($timezone = null, $time = null) {
    $oldtimezone = date_default_timezone_get();
    if (isset($timezone)) {
        date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
    }

    if (!isset($time)) {
        $time = time();
    }

    $tm = localtime($time, true);
    $isdst = $tm['tm_isdst'];
    $offset = 0;
    //$dsttime = mktime_array($tm);
    //echo strftime("%c", $dsttime);

    $tm['tm_isdst'] = 0;
    $nondsttime = mktime_array($tm);
    $offset = $nondsttime - $time;

    date_default_timezone_set($oldtimezone);

    return $offset != 0;
}

function mktime_array($tm) {
    return mktime($tm['tm_hour'], $tm['tm_min'], $tm['tm_sec'], $tm['tm_mon']+1, $tm['tm_mday'], $tm['tm_year']+1900, isset($tm['tm_isdst'])? $tm['tm_isdst']: -1);
}
```

And some code you can use to test it:

```
foreach (array(null, "Australia/Sydney", "UTC", "America/Los_Angeles") as $tz) {
    $isdst = is_dst($tz);
    if (isset($tz)) {
        echo $tz;
    }
    else {
        echo "current timezone";
    }
    echo " ";
    if ($isdst) {
        echo "has daylight savings now\n";
    }
    else {
        echo "has standard time now\n";
    }
}

// tests based on known transitions for Sydney (AEST)
foreach (array(null, "2011-04-03 01:59:00", "2011-04-03 02:00:00", "2011-10-02 01:59:00", "2011-10-02 03:00:00") as $timestr) {
    $tz = "Australia/Sydney";
    if (isset($timestr)) {
        $tm = strptime($timestr, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");
        $time = mktime_array($tm);
    }
    else {
        $time = time();
    }
    $isdst = is_dst($tz, $time);
    if (isset($tz)) {
        echo $tz;
    }
    else {
        echo "current timezone";
    }
    echo " ";
    if ($isdst) {
        echo "has daylight savings at $timestr\n";
    }
    else {
        echo "has standard time at $timestr\n";
    }
}
```

For me, it prints:

```
current timezone has daylight savings now
Australia/Sydney has daylight savings now
UTC has standard time now
America/Los_Angeles has standard time now
Australia/Sydney has daylight savings at 
Australia/Sydney has daylight savings at 2011-04-03 01:59:00
Australia/Sydney has standard time at 2011-04-03 02:00:00
Australia/Sydney has standard time at 2011-10-02 01:59:00
Australia/Sydney has daylight savings at 2011-10-02 03:00:00
```